# Azure Static Web App - React - Vite - CORS

Tags: reactjs, azure, cors, vite, azure-static-web-app

I have deployed a React SPA Static Web App. I'm using Vite, and in my vite.config I have set up a proxy that works during development.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
// import eslint from 'vite-plugin-eslint';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    build: {
        target: 'esnext',
    },
    server: {
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'https://externalAPI',
                changeOrigin: true,
                rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
            },
        },
    },
});
```

This, however, does not work on the deployed site, and I am getting CORS issues.

When I fetch data:

```
// this works for development, but during production it fetches clientURL/api/endpoint instead of externalAPI/api/endpoint 
// return fetch(`/api/Session/MakeSession`, {
       

// But this gives me CORS errors                 
return fetch(`https://externalAPI/api/Session/MakeSession`, {
headers: { accept: 'text/plain', token: res.accessToken },
                    });
                })
                .then((res) => {
                    if (!res.ok) {
                        throw new Error(`Failed to create session with status ${res.status}`);
                    }
                    return res.json();
                })
                .then((data) => {
                    setUserData(data);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
                });
        }
```

According to the network tab, it is trying to reach the correct url, but the exact error I'm getting is:
Access to fetch at 'https://externalAPI.com/api/Session/MakeSession' from origin 'https://clientURL.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I tried messing with the Vite config and proxy to no avail. I'm not super familiar with how SWA's work so there might be an issue there.
I tried adding 'no-cors' to the request, but that doesn't work for me, as I need more than an opaque response.
I don't have access to the server code, but I've been told that other external clients have accessed the API with no CORS issues.

Comment: Hope this Refer helps [MSDOC](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/static-web-apps/apis-container-apps.md) [MSDOC2](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-rest-api.md) and  [MSDOC3](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/container-apps/cors.md)

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are getting indicates that the external API you are trying to access does not have the necessary CORS headers set up to allow requests from your deployed site. To resolve this issue, you can configure CORS settings for your static web app.

- One way to do this is to use Azure Container Apps with Azure Static Web Apps. When you link your container app to your static web app, any requests to your static web app with a route that starts with `/api` are proxied to the same route on the container app.
- Another way is to configure CORS in the Azure portal for Azure Container Apps. You can enable and configure CORS in your container app by adding values specific to your configuration in the Azure portal. After adding values specific to your configuration, you can use the Azure container app ingress cors update to set the CORS configuration for your container app. This is due to the URL. CORS is a security feature implemented by web browsers that prevents web pages from making requests to a different domain than the one that served the webpage. Make sure to add `https://externalAPI/api/Session/MakeSession` also.
  [image]

If you don't want to use Azure Container Apps, you can also enable CORS support for your RESTful API in the Azure App Service.